# What are the benefits of ethereum 'archive' sync mode and who should use it?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, synchronization, fast-sync, state-trie-pruning

We have set up a private Ethereum node for our blockchain application connected to the mainnet. The node runs on a server with 2TB SSD, 4 CPU and 6GB memory. It's been syncing for about a week and is currently at block ~5,000,000 (around 900GB of disk space).

Since it's taking quite a long time to sync compared to the `fast` sync mode - which also takes less disk space - I wonder if there's any obvious benefits to running it in the `archive` mode and if we could potentially run into problems if we were to switch to the `fast` mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Archive nodes are only necessary if you're going to be querying historical nodes that are no longer on the state trie.

That said, even fast-pruned nodes allow you to inspect some (configurable) depth of history on the state trie, so whether it's sufficient depends on your use-case.

A cheat sheet: https://dev.to/5chdn/ethereum-node-configuration-modes-cheat-sheet-25l8